# Two number patterns (clue: or geometrical shapes)

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

Solve the series:

**Series 1:**

6 and 1

5 and 2

4 and 3

5 and 1

???

**Series 2:**

6 and 1

5 and 2

5 and 1

4 and 3

???